# How to use port 502

Tags: android, tcp, modbus

I'm trying to develop an app which needs to have modbus/TCP. The default port for Modbus/TCP is 502. I'm getting an error when I try to open a connection on port 502. I tried different ports and they were working. I think something is blocking port 502, but I couldn't figure it out.

This is the exception I'm getting: `01-01 00:01:44.309: I/System.out(953): S: Error java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

I have "INTERNET" permission

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPServer extends Thread {

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 502;
    public boolean running = true;
    public boolean receiving = false;
    private PrintWriter mOut;

    public TCPServer() {
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mOut != null && !mOut.checkError()) {
            mOut.println(message);
            mOut.flush();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        try {
            while (true) {
                while (running) {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                    serverSocket.setSoTimeout(500);
                    Socket tempSckt = new Socket();
                    boolean isConnected = false;
                    while (!isConnected && running) {
                        try {
                            tempSckt = serverSocket.accept();
                            isConnected = true;
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                    if (running) {
                        System.out.println("connected");
                        final Socket client = tempSckt;
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                receiving = true;
                                try {
                                    mOut = new PrintWriter(client
                                            .getOutputStream());
                                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                            new InputStreamReader(client
                                                    .getInputStream()));
                                    while (receiving) {
                                        String message = in.readLine();
                                        if (message != null) {
                                            // System.out.println(message);
                                            byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
                                            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
                                            for (byte b : bytes) {
                                                int val = b;
                                                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                                                    binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0
                                                            : 1);
                                                    val <<= 1;
                                                }
                                                binary.append(' ');
                                            }
                                            System.out.println("'" + message
                                                    + "' to binary: " + binary);
                                        } else {
                                            receiving = false;
                                        }
                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println("S: Error"
                                            + e.toString());
                                } finally {
                                    try {
                                        client.close();
                                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                        isConnected = false;
                    }

                    serverSocket.close();
                }
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("S: Error " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

My Application running as a system app. I did the necessary configurations. I checked it with ps shell command. It is working as a system app now. But still I am not able to bind to port 502.

Answer (score 1):

Ports below 1024 are restricted - only apps with root privileges can listen on those. Of course, your application isn't privileged.

That's the general rule on Linux/Unix (and Android is Linux-based).

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16568) for a rationale behind this restriction.

Comment: After your answer I tried and sucessfully ran my app as a system app. But I am still not able to bind to port 502.

Comment: Hm, another possibility (if you're running KitKat) is that SELinux policy disallows listening on low ports. See [this article](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/easily-change-your-android-selinux-mode/) on how to change SELinux settings.

Comment: I'm using Texas Instrument's Jelly Bean 4.2 Android Image on a BeagleBone Black. It's not KitKat but I looked up to the kernel files and found some SELinux files. I'm not entirely sure that these are the same as KitKat's SELinux files. I tried the app which mentioned in the link you gave. But It doesn't work naturally, because It needs KitKat.

Comment: I'm not sure how is SELinux set up in BeagleBone, but maybe you can try (in shell): `setenforce 0`?

Comment: I don't have setenforce in shell.